# Fixed: Webkit key frames image gallery not displaying all image

Tags: html, css, webkit

```css
.Image_Cont {
  top: 20%;
  left: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Scroll_Image {
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: slide_animation;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s; /* changed from 33s for demo purposes */
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}

.Image img {
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide_animation {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  10% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    left: 300px;
  }
  30% {
    left: 300px;
  }
  40% {
    left: 600px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 600px;
  }
  60% {
    left: 300px;
  }
  70% {
    left: 300px;
  }
  80% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  90% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="index.html" class="header-logo"> <img src="CSS/images/Logo.jpeg" alt="BeMe Logo"></a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="about_us.html">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="find_us.html">Find us</a></li>
        <li><a href="basket.html">Basket</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="Image_Cont">
      <div class="Scroll_Image">
        <div class="Image">
          <img src="CSS/images/Logo_Rot.jpeg" alt="Logo rotated">
        </div>
        <div class="Image">
          <img src="CSS/images/Female_Cln.jpeg" alt="Example of Female Clone">
        </div>
        <div class="Image">
          <img src="CSS/images/Male_Cln.jpeg" alt="Example of Male Clone">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

This is part of a website I need to build for my uni course work.

The gallery will display the first image and will rotate but it doesn't display the next image only the background color.

I've tried changing the webkit animation to go from left to right that didn't work.
The code validates without any errors.

I would like the three images to automatically rotate through

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue.

The images where loading in stacked on top of another. And the images where larger than the animation.

```
<!--- This is the working code-->
@-webkit-keyframes slide_animation{
  0%{bottom: 0px;}
  10%{bottom: 0px;}
  20%{bottom: 0px;}
  30%{bottom: 450px;}
  40%{bottom: 450px;}
  50%{bottom: 900px;}
  60%{bottom: 900px;}
  70%{bottom: 450px;}
  80%{bottom: 450px;}
  90%{bottom: 0px;}
  100%{bottom: 0px;}
}
```